# Dealing with Deep Multiple instance learning

Tags: python

I am writing to inquire about the error when I utilize Deep Multiple instance learning in my image classification task.
but I encountered an error such as the image, but I don't know how to solve it,
Would anyone please teach me how to solve this problem? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The error has nothing to do with multiple instance learning, it's a numpy error, print the shape of img_data before the subtraction. So that, we can get the reason for the error.

Comment: @furcifer Sorry, can you please explain more? Because I don’t know how to solve it, thank you very much!

Comment: I just said while running the code, just do a print(img_data.shape) before the error line so that we know why the error?